# How to find files containing two strings together in Linux?

Tags: linux

I want to find files containing two strings together, for example the file contains both `string1` and `string2`.

I want the full path of files in output. I don't want to see "permission denied" warnings.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
grep -l string2 `grep -l string1 /path/*`
```

which is the same as

```
grep -l string2 $(grep -l string1 /path/*)
```

---

Edit: heres why `grep string1 /path/* | grep string2` doesn't do what I think alwbtc wants.

```
$ cd /tmp
$ cat a
apples
oranges
bananas
$ cat b
apples
mangoes
lemons
$ cat c
mangoes
limes
pears
$ cd ~
$ grep apples /tmp/* | grep mangoes
$
```

Nothing found, but file b contains both strings.

Here's what I think alwbtc wants

```
$ grep -l apples $(grep -l mangoes /tmp/*)
/tmp/b
```

Comment: This is a neat solution and more useful than mine. For those that want to know what is going on here (it took me a bit to figure out), he's using the `-l` option to return the file names instead of the lines. He's then using the dollar sign or the back quotes to pass that list as the `FILE` argument into the second grep. This allows the second grep to search the entirety of each file found instead of the individual lines as in my solution.

Comment: You missed a `-l` option for both commands to be considered equal.

Comment: @embedded.kyle this doesn't work for filenames containing spaces or newlines

Comment: grep -l word1 $(grep -r -l word2 .)

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for an extensible way to do 2 *or more* strings and came up with this:

```
grep -rl string1 path-to-files | xargs grep -l string2 | xargs grep -l string3
```

The first grep recursively finds the names of files containing `string1` within `path-to-files`.

The results are piped into `xargs` which runs one or more grep commands on those files for `string2`.

The results are then piped into another `xargs` command for `string3` - it's the same as the first `xargs` call, but looking for a different string.

The use of `xargs` will avoid problems where there are so many results that the resultant command line from the use of back-ticks is too long.

To avoid the warnings we can redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null`:

```
grep -rl string1 path-to-files  2>/dev/null | xargs grep -l string2
```

It's not needed on the subsequent grep calls because `string1` has already been found inside the file so the permissions are known to be good.

Comment: Nice solution. Especially if you work with a large data set and want to see results fast. But if you have white space in your filenames, add something like `-d '\n'` to xargs.

Comment: If the filenames contain white-space it may be better to use `-Z` or `--null` as an argument to the grep calls and `-0` (dash zero) to xargs. Filesnames are not allowed to contain the null character so it's a safe delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the equivalent [ack](/questions/tagged/ack) command to [RedGrittyBrick's answer](https://superuser.com/a/437397/197238):

```
ack string2 $(ack string1 -l)
```

Works the same way (except `ack` by default searches the current directory recursively). The contents within the `$()` searches for `string1` but `-l` outputs only the filenames where that string was found. They are then passed as arguments into the outer command, which means `string2` is searched for within those list of files only.

Comment: This works also with `ag`.

Answer (score 2):

For filenames that include spaces I recommend:

```
grep -rlZ 'string1' /absolute/path/to/search/dir | xargs -0 grep -l 'string2'
```

If you want the output in a txt file you can add:

```
grep -rlZ 'string1' /absolute/path/to/search/dir | xargs -0 grep -l 'string2' > './paths.txt'
```

grep flags:

- -r (--recursive)  recursively search through all files in all directories under the provided file
- -l (--files-with-matches)  print just the path/filenames of the files without showing the actual match
- -Z (--null)  output NUL terminated file names

xargs flags:

- -0 (--null) tells xargs to read NUL terminated arguments

Credit to answer by @Hasturkun [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296525/grep-and-sed-with-spaces-in-filenames)

Answer (score 1):

Pipe one `grep` into another:

`grep "string1" /path/to/files/* | grep "string2"`

Comment: If the two strings are on different lines in the file, this wont work.

Comment: I didn't know there was a requirement for them to be in the same line @RedGrittyBrick

Comment: @slhck: I've updated my answer to show what I think alwbtc wants and why this answer doesn't do that. Of course, I may have misunderstood what alwbtc wants and embedded.kyle may have got it right - I suspect not though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find`.

`-exec` in `find` is usually interpreted as an action, but it's also a test. Such test is true iff what you execute returns exit status `0`. `grep` returns exit status `0` iff there is a match. This is how you use `grep` in such tests:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q string1 {} \; -exec grep -q string2 {} \; -print
```

Notes:

- `string1` and `string2` are patterns. Use `grep -F` for fixed strings.
- The solution is portable.
- It's dead easy to add more tests with `grep`.
- It's easy to add more arbitrary tests.
- It's possible to build complex logic (see "Theory" in [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1577902/432690)).
- The solution works well with pathnames with spaces, newline characters etc. Ambiguity may arise when a pathname containing newline is printed, because `-print` terminates pathnames with newlines; but this is a disadvantage of `-print` and therefore in general you shouldn't parse what it prints.

  `-print0` instead of `-print` will allow you to pipe to `xargs -0` and to do something with matching files. `find … -print0 | xargs -0 …` is a common way to handle arbitrary pathnames, not portable though. While you can replace non-portable `-print0` with portable `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +`, there is no portable equivalent of `xargs -0`. The right portable way to do something with matching files is to add another `-exec` after all the tests.
- The easiest way to hide `permission denied` is to redirect stderr to `/dev/null` (`find … 2>/dev/null`), but then you won't see other errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0):

```
comm -12 <(grep --fixed-strings --files-with-matches "STRING1" /path/to/files/* 2>/dev/null | sort) <(grep --fixed-strings --files-with-matches "STRING1" /path/to/files/* 2>/dev/null | sort)
```

or less redundantly:

```
search_files () { str="$1"; shift; grep -Fl "$str" "$@" 2>/dev/null | sort; }
comm -12 <(search_files "STRING1" /path/to/files/*) <(sf "STRING2" /path/to/files/*)
```

This will work if the strings are on different lines of the same file and will also avoid false positives if a filename contains one of the strings.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @RedGrittyBrick's solution which has a shortcoming when running the command unattended plus to suppress error output as intended and to find files recursively you might consider

`grep -l 'STRING1' $(! grep -lrs 'STRING2' /absolute/path/to/search/dir && echo /dev/null)`

`-s` option will suppress error messages
`-r` option allows to search for strings in arbitrarily nested directories
`!` combined with `&& echo /dev/null` guarantees that the command won't hang up. Otherwise, if the `inner grep` doesn't find any file it won't output anything so that the `outer grep` will indefinitely wait for input to search upon. This solution outputs `/dev/null` in these cases so `outer grep` will search for `STRING1` in `/dev/null` where it's supposed to not finding anything.

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually do this is with `-C numberOfLines` in GNU or BSD `grep`:

`grep -C 9999 STRING1 | grep STRING2`

What `-C` does in this case is show context of 9999 lines before and after every hit for STRING1. If that context contains STRING2 then the second `grep` after the pipe will get it. Replace 9999 with whatever big number you like. It's a little hacky but always works for me.

More on the `-C` command here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081/grep-show-lines-surrounding-each-match

Comment: How does this command find files? I mean if I have many files in a directory, how can your command tell me the paths to the files that contain both strings? The OP explicitly asks for paths.

Answer (score 0):

It will find all the files, which contain three words(Status, ACTIVE, INACTIVE)

```
grep -l Status $(grep -l ACTIVE $(grep -r -l INACTIVE .))
```

Comment: Like some other answers here, this relies on the shell splitting words from unquoted `$(...)`. If pathnames contain spaces then this approach will fail miserably. If they contain wildcard characters (especially `*`) then it may give you false results.