# Find hidden files in non-hidden directories

Tags: bash, search, find

Consider following directory structure:

```
$ find m
m
m/f.sh
m/.a
```

I want to find hidden files in non-hidden directories with:

```
find . -not -path "*/.*" -and -name "*.*"
.
./m/f.sh
```

but only `f.sh` is found, where I expect to find also `.a`. When searching without `-not -path` part, all hidden files are found:

```
find . -name "*.*"
./m/f.sh
./m/.a
```

How can I specify to search non-hidden directories, but match also hidden files?

To clarify:

- `./non-hidden-dir/.hidden-dir/.hidden-file` should be found.
- `./.hidden-dir/non-hidden-dir/.hidden-file` should not be found.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I think it complicates the question. I simply want to find hidden files in non-hidden directories. When searched without `-not -path` part but with "*.*" pattern for `-name` hidden files are displayed as well. Please see edited question.

Comment: You're not helping me helping you. Please answer "yes" or "no": (1) Should `./non-hidden-dir/.hidden-dir/.hidden-file` be found? (2) Should `./.hidden-dir/non-hidden-dir/.hidden-file` be found?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski 1) yes; 2) no;

Comment: So the top level subdirectory is the one that counts. Somewhat surprising but so be it.

Answer (score 1):

About what you tried:

- `-not -path "*/.*"` evaluates to false for any pathname containing `/.`. It excludes all hidden files and prunes all hidden subdirectories (not like `-prune` because their content will be tested, still the test will always turn out false).
- `-name "*.*"` evaluates to true for any basename containing `.`, regardless if the dot appears in front (`.a`) or somewhere else (`f.sh`).

It seems you want to prune top level directories that are hidden. Everywhere else you want to find hidden files. So this:

```
find . -path './.*' -prune -o -name '.*'
```

The above code effectively treats `.` as non-hidden and **it uses the POSIX definition of "file"** which says [a directory is also a file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690). If you meant "hidden regular files" then the code should be:

```
find . -type d -path './.*' -prune -o -type f -name '.*' -print
```

Notes:

- `-not` and `-and` you used are not portable; the portable equivalents are `!` and `-a` respectively (and you may or may not omit `-a`).
- [This answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1577902/432690) may be helpful in learning how `find` works.