# Look for a directory that contains two files of which the names are known

Tags: linux, find

I wrote some code a while ago, and stored it in `main.c`. I then compiled it to `test`, and left it for a month or so while I waited for a use case to run my test.

This is a shared server, so things get moved around. The parent directory has a lot of other `main.c` and a lot of other `test` files, so what I'm looking for is a directory that contains both `main.c` and `test`. I can filter from there if there's a few results

Is this doable with `mlocate`/`find`? I could write something with `sed` to truncate the directory returned by `find`, and then run that through another iteration of `find`, but I'd prefer if there's a built-in solution that I can trust.

Answer (score 1):

#### With `mlocate`

This works in my Kubuntu:

```
mlocate -b --regex '^(main.c|test)$' | sed 's|/[^/]*$||' | sort | uniq -d
```

<sup>(tested with `mlocate 0.26`).</sup>

Note: this does not scale. If you want to find directories with three (or more) known files then you need to replace `uniq -d` with something more sophisticated (`uniq -dc` is a good start).

---

#### With `find`

This solution is relatively slow but does not rely on `mlocate` which is not portable.

Basic solution that tests directories for existence of two regular files with known names:

```
find / -type d -exec test -f {}/main.c \; -exec test -f {}/test \; -print
```

Note: this scales well. Adding few more tests for more names is trivial.

And to clarify: in `test -f {}/test` the first `test` is the standard utility named `test` (a.k.a. `[`), it has nothing to do with your `test`. If you named the file `test1` then the snippet would be `test -f {}/test1`.

POSIX specification of `find` requires its `-exec` primary to substitute one `{}` that appears as a separate argument. Substituting more than one `{}` or substituting `{}` being only a part of an argument (like in `{}/main.c`) is allowed but not required. Therefore the above command may or may not work with your `find` (it works with GNU `find` for sure). Below is a fully portable (but slower) alternative:

```
find / -type d -exec sh -c 'test -f "$1/main.c" && test -f "$1/test"' find-sh {} \; -print
```

<sup>(`find-sh` is explained here: [What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)).</sup>

When starting from `/` you probably want to exclude `/proc`, `/sys`, and `/dev`:

```
find / -type d \( -path /proc -o -path /sys -o -path /dev \) -prune -o \
       -exec test -f {}/main.c \; -exec test -f {}/test \; -print
```

If you want to implement more advanced exclusions/inclusions then please see [*Recursively search files with exclusions and inclusions*](https://superuser.com/q/1577775/432690) and [my answer there](https://superuser.com/a/1577902/432690).

If your `test` supports `-O` (to test if the file is effectively owned by you) then consider `test -O` instead of `test -f`. This way you won't find somebody else's files. Notes:

- `test` from GNU Coreutils does support `-O`.
- `test` run directly from `find -exec` is a standalone executable (it may be the GNU `test`) but `test` run from `sh` may be a shell builtin which is different. To run the executable specify its full path (e.g. `/usr/bin/test`).