# ls -R instead of find

Tags: find, ls

I can see `ls -R` lists all files and folders. I can `grep` the file name from the list.

What are the advantages of "find" ?

Also, any caveats if I use `ls -R` instead of `find`?

Answer (score 1):

`ls` lists files on or inside the arguments while `find` finds files, their purpose is completely different and they have nothing to do with each other

- `ls` doesn't do any globbing, so if you want to find names matching something in **any subdirectories** then it doesn't work at all, unless your shell supports [globstar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62665/44425). In that case `find . -name '*some*thing*.*some*ext'` is equivalent to `ls **/*some*thing*.*some*ext`
- `ls` won't list hidden files and folders unless `-a` is used so `ls -R` isn't the equivalent to `find .` at all
- Some `find` implementations like GNU or BSD also support matching with regex. You can't use `ls` to lists files matching a regex
- Piping `ls` output to commands like `ls -Ra | grep` is a bad thing to do because it won't work with files containing newlines in their names. It's worse if `ls` is aliased to use some arguments that print special characters differently. Many people also use `ls` output in `for` loops and that might fail in even more cases. See [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425), [Parsing ls, not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19574307/995714), [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). With `find` it's always safe: `find . -name 'pattern' -exec command {}` or `find . -name 'pattern' -print0 | xargs -0 your command`
- Because `ls` is just a listing tool, you can't find files matching complex conditions like *(`*.txt` in `folderA`) or (`*.cfg` in folderB and grandparent is `folderC`) or (isExecutable or hasMode(0624) or (file.ext and isNewerThan(today)) or (somefile in folders at 3-5 levels deep)*...

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski actually according to POSIX [find is intended to `find files`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/find.html), and GNU find says `search for files in a directory hierarchy`. But indeed BSD find says `walk a file hierarchy`

Answer (score 0):

#### Fundamental difference between `ls` and `find`

[This other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1799543/432690) is good, it makes several valid points; but it does not explicitly state what I find the fundamental difference between `ls` and `find`. I won't repeat the points, the purpose of my answer is to emphasize the fundamental difference. Here it is:

**`ls` lists files. `find` evaluates an expression.**

The [specification of `find`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) or `man 1 find` in your Linux/Unix may welcome you with the following line:

> `find` - find files

and you may wonder what the difference between "finding" and "listing" is. This "find files" is kinda misleading. The real purpose of `find` is revealed later in the description:

> The `find` utility shall recursively descend the directory hierarchy from each file specified by `path`, evaluating a Boolean expression composed of the primaries […] for each file encountered.

If the expression contains (explicit or implicit) `-print`, then yes, `find` "finds files", i.e. it prints their pathnames, therefore it's similar to `ls`. But you are not limited to this. You can build custom, arbitrary expressions. You can make `find` *do something* with files or because of files.

I have used `find` to answer many question on this site and thus I can give you several examples that illustrate what I mean. Where I link to an answer, I urge you to also read the respective question to see what problem the answer is supposed to solve.

My examples:

- [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1577902/432690) describes how `find` works in general (the "theory" part) and then (later parts) concentrates on finding files where tests base on pathnames. From it you can learn the "philosophy" of `find`.
- [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1730694/432690) builds custom tests that use `grep` for the purpose of finding files.
- [This question](https://superuser.com/q/1222165/432690) is a basic example of the ability of `find` to do something to files (in this particular case: to delete files).
- The "portable solution" in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1719587/432690) makes `find` run a shell (or shells) to do a custom action to files (in this case: to move them). Additionally there's an implementation of a counter that limits the solution to 1000 successful actions.
- [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1687310/432690) uses `find` not to find (list) files per se, nor to do anything to files, but to do something because of files. The goal is to count files. The "analysis" part may give you some insight into what `ls` is *not* designed for.

I consider `ls` as a rather specialized tool whose output is designed to be human-readable, while `find` is more general and its *scope* reaches beyond finding or listing files. `find` alone cannot fully replace `ls` though; `ls` supports options for sorting entries, `find` does not (see [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/181787)).

---

#### Specific difference between verbatim `ls -R` and sole `find`

> any caveats if I use `ls -R` instead of `find`?

Aside from the general "do not parse `ls`" advice and other points made by the [already linked answer](https://superuser.com/a/1799543/432690), I note that in general the output of `ls -R` consists of blocks of the form:

```
./path/to/subdir:
filename 1
filename 2
another filename
```

If you "`grep` the file name from the list" then you will see zero or more entries, each being either a pathname of some subdirectory (with `:` appended!) or a filename of some file. It's easy to get filename(s) without information where (in what subdirectory) the file(s) are.

On the other hand sole `find` (which for many implementations is equivalent to `find . -print`) gives you pathnames, always. While using `grep` on the output of `find` is not necessarily the best idea (the best idea may be to create a good expression with `-name`, `-path`, `-regex` (if supported) or so), it's almost always better than using `grep` on the output of `ls -R`; unless you just want to know if a file with a matching name exists, not *where* it exists.